# How to case-insensitively set value in object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to set value in object in Javascript when you don't know the key pattern?

Example:

**Key value is same**  , but some time it is in **CAPITAL** or some time it is in lowercase or sometime the first letter is in uppercase and other lowercase.

```
var a = {
    'perm city' :{
         value:'asda'
    }
}

if((a['perm city'] && a['perm city'].value) ||  (a['Perm City'] && a['Perm City'].value) ||  (a['PERM CITY'] && a['PERM CITY'].value)){
    a['PERM CITY'] = 'DADASDASD'
}
```

In my example, I want to set `perm city` value but I don't know which pattern it will come out.

Comment: If the object `a` has all its property names in lower case you can just check `a[propertyName.toLowerCase()]`

Comment: what is suppose to happen if you have all 3 cases?

Comment: as I told you i don't know at what format will come

Comment: I want to set the value in this property

Comment: @user944513 your code includes 3 properties. Here they are:
`perm city`, `Perm City`, & `PERM CITY`

are they all equal? are they 3 different things?

Comment: only one property come .but I don't know on which format it will come

Comment: So, you know the key (e.g. 'PERM CITY') and have a new value for it (e.g. 'DADASDASD'). But you need to find (if exists) inside the object existing value to update it, while the key in the object may be in different lettercase?

Comment: key may be 'PERM CITY' or 'perm city' or 'Perm City'

Comment: YFYI: In a previous version of JS, one could have done `(a["perm city"] || a["PERM CITY"]) = "DASDASD";`, however thats a syntax error now :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to search for the key by comparing it to a lowercase version of it.
If no key was found, set the key to a default lowercase value: `perm city`

```js
const data = {
  'perm city': {
    value: 'asda'
  }
};

console.log(data);

const defaultKey = 'perm city';

const keys = Object.keys(data);

let foundKey = keys.find((key) => key.toLowerCase() === defaultKey);

foundKey = foundKey || defaultKey;

data[foundKey] = 'PIZZA';

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would normalize all the keys to follow the same pattern firstly (all keys to be lowercase), and later work with the normalized data:

```js
const data = {
 'Key': 1,
 'test': 2,
 'Perm city': 3
}

// Normalize the data keys
Object.keys(data)
  .forEach(key => {
    // Normalize the key
    data[key.toLowerCase()] = data[key]
    
    // Delete the denormalized key with its value
    delete data[key]
  })

console.log(data['perm city'], data)
```

Comment: If you're going to normalise the keys, it might be a good idea to also `delete` the non-normalised key, so you don't have duplicate properties that get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You could `find` the relevant key amongst all object keys

```
let relevantKey = Object.keys( a ).find( key => {
    let s = 'PERM CITY'
    return (key.toLowerCase( ) === s.toLowerCase( ) )
})
```

Comment: Why `.filter()` -> `.shift()` instead of just `.find()`?

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the keys of a *Object*, then find the key you need by doing a case insensitive search. Use the found key to assign to original *Object*.

```
let obj = { "X": 1 };
let key_to_find = "x";
key = Object.keys(obj).find(function(element) {
  return element.toLowerCase() == key_to_find;
});
obj[key||key_to_find] = "new value";
```

Comment: obj[key || key_to_find] = "new value";   Otherwise you may have 'undefined' key in your object

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using a function to set a value for your obj :

```
 var a = {
    'perm city' :{
     value:'asda'
    }
 }


    function changeValue(obj,prop,value) {
        let propUp = prop.toUpperCase();
        let propDown = prop.toLowerCase();
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propUp)) {
          obj[propUp] = value;
        }
        else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propDown)) {
                obj[propDown] = value;
        }
        else {
                console.log("No prop found in low or Uppercase")
        }
        console.log(obj);
    }
    changeValue(a,"PERM CITY","NEW");
```

The new obj will be :

```
{
        'perm city' :{
         value:'NEW'
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function assignKeyValueCaseInsensitively(type, key, value) {
  if ((type != null) && (typeof key === 'string')) {

    var isKeyRespondsInitially = false;
    var regXKey = RegExp(key, 'i');

    Object.keys(type).forEach(function (key) {
      if (regXKey.test(key)) {
        isKeyRespondsInitially = true;

        type[key] = value;
      }
    });
    if (!isKeyRespondsInitially) {

      type[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return type;
}

var a = {
  'perm city' : 'foo',
  'PERM CITY' : 'bar',
  'Perm City' : 'baz',
  'permCity' : 'biz'
};
var b = {
  'permCity' : 'biz'
}

assignKeyValueCaseInsensitively(a, 'pERM citY', 'boz');
assignKeyValueCaseInsensitively(b, 'pERM citY', 'boz');

console.log('a : ', a);
console.log('b : ', b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```